# Visual Basic Dynamic Textbox

Tags: vb.net

App & Code[image]

```
Private Sub PriceBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PriceBox.Click
    If CmbSize.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        PriceBox.Text = "£30"
    ElseIf CmbSize.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        PriceBox.Text = "£40"
    ElseIf CmbSize.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        PriceBox.Text = "£50"
    End If

End Sub
```

This Code works but only when clicked, What sub do i need to use for it to change automatically when Combobox index is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox has [SelectedIndexChanged-event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can use:

```
Private Sub CmbSize_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmbSize.SelectedIndexChanged   

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want user changes of the index and not programmatic changes then use

SelectionChangeCommitted

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the SelectedIndexChanged on the CmbSize control as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2